# how to make work absolute css, js and others paths on localhost using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My index.php file having absolute path for CSS, JS, Images and fonts. like following.

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>.................many more.
```

it works good when it is on server(website). but when i moved whole website to my localhost inside a directory (http://127.0.0.1/example/) then my css and js file starts linking here :

```
http://127.0.0.1/css/style.css
http://127.0.0.1/js/jquery.js
```

but they should be linking here:

```
http://127.0.0.1/example/css/style.css
http://127.0.0.1/example/js/jquery.js
```

i have tried this these lines in my local .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example/
```

but still css,js,images and fonts not pointing correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On localhost you can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^((?:css|js)/.+)$ /example/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: as you said i added these lines in my http://127.0.0.1/example/.htaccess file but not working.

Comment: No I wrote to add it in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file (parent of example directory)

Comment: but i think adding 127.0.0.1/.htaccess here will affect my other projects..?

Comment: 1. It cannot be controlled from `/example/.htaccess`. 2. It will only affect `/css/` and `/js/` paths.

Comment: anyways because it is working then is the Answer. no matter it will affecting my other projects or not. Thank you @anubhava